# Как управлять музыкой жестами в Phonegap?

Tags: android, phonegap

Для того что бы появилось уведомление с управлением музыкой (кнопками):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть плагин [cordova-plugin-music-controls](https://github.com/homerours/cordova-music-controls-plugin), всё работает уведомление появляется как на скриншоте события от кнопок ловятся, оно даже отображается на заблокированном экране.
Но на телефонах бывает управление жестами при выключенном экране, например свайп в право, когда экран выключен, переключает песню. Вот эти жести не отлавливаются этим плагином. Так же заметил что на заблокированном экране вся музыка (vk, yandex и т.д.) [имеет одинаковый вид](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipN2wE3eP1tCHmhj5GrrPoJuVUaIujlkX2jfzXXlhfSA4XfShs5Eb-P56YtZr2jjPQ?key=WVJQX3JRNURyMUFZaGg2MkxzWkdrVHQ0Wm42YklR) и соответственно вся управляется жестами.
Но уведомление с этого плагина выглядит [везде одинаково, в том числе и на экране блокировке](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipM5R8dPuiHxjjl039DjytJmmq_fWHrIa3Q4l_IKRcUFw1JEp-c70dlnY5ZQQpaO_g?key=M0NUUzhNUnI3bUZ0bjAtTDAwRVhETzV3c0RyS2dR), но не так-как другие приложения.
Я так понимаю приложение должно использовать какие-то стандартные методы для создания этого уведомления, а не создавать его само.
Можно ли как-то на Phonegap сделать управление музыкой, что бы оно отображалось на экране блокировки "в стандартном виде" и управлять можно было жестами?